# Binding ASP.NET GridView to an Oracle SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview, sys-refcursor

We have a Procedure in Oracle with a SYS_REFCURSOR output parameter that returns the data we want to bind to an ASP.NET GridView control. I've seen this done before but I can't find the original reference I used to solve the problem.

Here is what the procedure looks like:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETSOMEDATA
(
    P_Data OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN P_Data FOR SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;
END GETSOMEDATA;
```

And for now the GridView is just bare-bones:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like: (didn't specify which language)

```
    Public Function GetSomeData() as DataTable
        Dim OrclConn as New OracleConnection("Connectionstring")
        Dim OrclCmd as New Oraclecommand("GETSOMEDATA", OrclConn)
        OrclCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        OrclCmd.Parameters.Add("P_Data", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 'Or ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

        Dim OrclDA as New OracleDataAdapter(OrclCmd)
        Dim RtnTable as DataTable
        OrclConn.Open
        OrclDA.Fill(RtnTable)
        OrclConn.Close

        Return RtnTable
    End Function
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. To bind this data to the GridView, just set the GridView's DataSource = RtnTable and call DataBind().

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim oracon As New OracleConnection("User Id=developer;Password=developer;Data Source=orcl;")
        Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
        Dim qry As String
        oracon.Open()
        qry = "select * from Employee"
        Dim adp As New OracleDataAdapter(qry, oracon)
        adp.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        oracon.Close()
```